# Solutions for Paul Wilmott Derivatives Book

Tags: derivatives

I am looking for solutions manual for Derivatives, "the theory and practice of financial engineering". I'm not sure if the manual is published ever but I couldn't get it.

I would be more than happy if anyone by chance have the solutions and share it with me.

Best,

Comment: Alternatively you can ask here under the tag "homework/self-study" for those assignments you're having a problem with.

Comment: It's not for assignments Sanjay, I'm self studying. End of chapter questions in this particular book is different in a good way. For example "Write a program to value a down-and-out call option, with barrier below the strike price."